# Can someone explain the inner working of the symbols at the end of this bash: “_ {} \;”

Tags: bash, shell, find, exec

I ran the following command in shell to batch convert `.HEIC` files to `.JPG` files, the command is successful, however there's a part of it I don't understand:

```
find . -name '*.HEIC' -exec sh -c 'magick convert $1 "${1%.HEIC}.JPG"' _ {} \;
```

Apparently `_ {}` acts to assign `find` result to `$1`, but how? I can't find an explanation on google nor here, and didn't have any luck with `man find`. It's entirely possible that answers were here but these symbols are not very nice to search for.

So the question is, how does `_ {}` assign variable to `$1`? Is it possible to assign multiple variable to it with find/ or other commands?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two things involved in how `_ {}` assigns the filename to `$1`. First, is how the `find`'s `-exec` works: it runs the following arguments (up to the escaped `;`) as a command, but with `{}` replaced with the path to the file it found. Thus, if it finds `./somefile.HEIC`, it'll run the equivalent of the command:

```
sh -c 'magick convert $1 "${1%.HEIC}.JPG"' _ ./somefile.HEIC
```

The second part is the `sh` command. `sh` can do a number of things, but if it's given a `-c` option, it takes the immediately following argument (`magick convert $1 "${1%.HEIC}.JPG"`) as a command string to parse and run, sort of like a little mini-script. The arguments after that are taken as arguments to that mini-script, starting with `$0`. In this case, that means it runs the mini-script with `$0` set to `_`, and `$1` set to "./somefile.HEIC". If more arguments were supplied, they'd be `$2`, `$3`, etc.

Comment: Thanks, this is very clear and helpful. Does this mean that _ is not necessary and I can just use $0 instead? Is there any benefit to use $1?

Comment: Also if I'm not wrong, the command starts one child/mini script for each of the file returned from find.

Comment: @Inian Correct on both counts. You could use `$0` to pass the filename, but `$0` is normally the name of the program (script, executable, etc) being executed, and using it as the file being operating on can lead to some confusion. ("_" isn't really a very good program name either, but at least it's not actively misleading.) As for running the mini-script for each file, that's how `-exec ... \;` works. If you use `-exec ... +`, it'll run them in big batches, so the filenames will be `$1`, `$2`, ... `${148}` or whatever. You can do this, but then you need a processing loop in the mini-script.