# In this code, why must we insert bash after find ... -exec ? ; and what's the difference between {} and ${} references?

Tags: bash, reference, command-line-interface, exec, dollar-sign

I've been using "find -exec" commands as in code 1 and 2:

**Code 1**

```
find . -type d -exec chmod 775 {} +
```

**Code 2**

```
find . -type f -exec mv {} ./.. \;
```

But sometimes I see people use "bash" or "sh" just after "-exec" as in code 3 and 4:

**Code 3**

```
alias foo="find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -exec sh -c 'echo \"\$(find \"{}\" -type f | wc -l)\" {}' \; | sort -nr
```

**Code 4**

```
alias foo="find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -exec bash -c 'echo \"\$(find \"\${1}\" -type f | wc -l) \"\${1}\" \"' -- \"{}\" \; | sort -nr"
```

**Question 1abc**: When do we use bash or sh after -exec ? Is there something special about echo as opposed to chmod and mv? Does echo belong to bash and if so, how do I know what other commands need bash in front?

Code 4 was a proposed improvement upon Code 3 because
they said "*you should pass the filename to the inner find command as an argument. Otherwise you will run into problems if one of your folders has a name with a " in it:*" , which I can understand.

**Question 2abc**:
I don't understand how ${1} makes it safer than {}? Don't they reference the same thing?
I tried replacing the last \"{}\" part with \"\${1}\" like below but it fails strangely. I don't understand why.

**Code 5**

```
alias foo="find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -exec bash -c 'echo \"\$(find \"\${1}\" -type f | wc -l) \"\${1}\" \"' -- \"\${1}\" \; | sort -nr"
```

Comment: These are many questions stuffed into one - ideally you'd ask them separately. To get you started, [here](https://arp242.net/make-find-exec-faster.html) is an article I *just* bumped into that's relevant.

Comment: The thing after `-exec` can only be a simple command, not a pipeline (like `find ... | wc -l`). Anytime you need the more complex features that a shell provides, you need to run a shell (like `bash`) to provide them. See the "why the original didn't work" section of my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55504207/bash-exit-a-script-when-a-specified-folder-is-empty-via-the-find-command/55505692#55505692). As for, `{}` and `${1}`, that has to do with passing the filename from `find` to `bash` (with `{}`) and then from `bash` to the actual command being executed (with `${1}`).

Comment: @GordonDavisson Question 1 = OK. Thanks, I understand about -exec now. That information was very vital.
Would you know what I would have to search on the internet to bring up explanations or examples about the use of {} and ${1}? (as I don't know the proper terminology)

Comment: @BenjaminW. Thanks! That link really made me understand -exec and its limitations more.

Comment: @MarkB Hah, I thought I'd written something about that before; see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53236018/bash-find-exec-sh-c-inner-working-of-symbols), and a more extensive discussion (with many irrelevant variations) [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/493808/commands-differences-using-quotations-find).

Comment: Thanks, those links really helped me understand more!